# How to show only post title in homepage of blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I want to show only post title and hide [post description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2WB7.jpg) in the homepage of my [blog](https://netflixdunia.blogspot.com/?m=1),
I have used fletro pro blogger template.

XML file of blog - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Srqaep3d6PtUklTFX630vV53DPZbJKuo/view?usp=drivesdk

and this is my blog - https://netflixdunia.blogspot.com/?m=1

Till now I applied this code

```
    <b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'> 
<style>
.post-description {
display:none;
}
</style>       
     </b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change post-description to pSnpt for fletro blogger templates, if you have any other template then view page source find perfect class for post [description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTfiM.jpg) here pSnpt is the post description class.

Paste the code below `]]></b:skin>`

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'> 
<style>
.pSnpt {display:none;}
</style>       
     </b:if>
```